# Creating Google Map instance in typescript class

Tags: google-maps, typescript

Hi I'm new to Typescript and Javascript and I'm having a few problems creating a googlemap instance.

I've downloaded the [google.maps.d.ts](http://nuget.org/packages/google.maps.d.ts/) declaration file and imported it to my typescript class like so, all the intellisense works fine etc.;

```
import googleMaps = module("google.maps"); 
module Mapping {
    export class GoogleMap implements IMap {

        public name: string;
        private map: any;
        private options: any;

        constructor (mapDiv:Element) {
            this.name = "GoogleMap";
            this.options = { zoom: 3, MapTypeId: 'terrian' };
            this.map = new googleMaps.google.maps.Map(mapDiv, this.options);
         }
    }
}
```

When I try to create this class in my index.cshtml file ;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>TypeScript Mapping</title></head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?    key=MYKEYGOESHERE&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/require.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/typings/Mapping.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {

            var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");

            var googleMap = new Mapping.GoogleMap(mapCanvas);
        }
    </script>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map" style="height: 512px; width: 512px;"></div>
```

I get the following error ;

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Module name "google.maps" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

What am I missing in order to load the googlemaps api?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you are including Google Maps as a `script` tag on your page, you probably don't want to use a module-loader to load it in.

So I would replace:

```
import googleMaps = module("google.maps");
```

With

```
/// <reference path="./google.maps.d.ts" />
```

The reference says to TypeScript "I will make sure this script is available at runtime".

The import statement says "Go and load this script for me at runtime".

Comment: Thanks Steve , I'll give that a go when I get back into the office

Answer (score 0):

I liked to create something called a `shim` function which let me work with window variables/objects (like `google`). I created that `.ts` file:

```
// -- Shim.ts:

/**
 * Loads variable from window according to
 * the name parameter.
 * 
 * @export
 * @param {string} name
 * @returns {*} window[name]
 */
export function shim(name: string): any {
    let global: any = window;
    return global[name];
}
```

My basic setup than looks like:

```
- main.ts
-- shims
-- -- Shim.ts
-- -- Google.ts
-- -- Swiper.ts
-- -- ... .ts
```

and the Google.ts would than simply use that function like:

```
// -- Google.ts

import { shim } from '../shims/Shim';

/**
 * Loads variable from window with the
 * name 'google'
 * 
 * @export
 * @returns {*} window['google']
 */
export let google = shim('google');
```

and whereever you than want to use the google variable simply include it like:

```
import { google } from '../shims/Google';
```

Maybe also have a look at the [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) - Typings is the simple way to manage and install TypeScript definition - which helped me a lot.

I currently wrote another Typescript Google Maps Setup and thought about sharing it with the community.

You can check it out using this link: https://github.com/DominikAngerer/typescript-google-maps